# Localize an array

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express to create an app for WP7. I need to localize the strings for finnish and swedish. Simple strings are not a problem. I have my AppResources..... files and its working.
But I also need to localize an array.
Example: An array of possible expense types

```
0 => Hotel,
1 => Taxi, ......
```

I will only save the array key and need to be able to show the type as string to the user.
With Android (Eclipse) i can make a string-array in my strings.xml

```
<string-array name="expense_types">
        <item>Hotel</item>
        <item>Taxi</item>.......
```

I have searched the intertubes in wain for a solution to this that would not be kludge. Of course I could check the culture and hard code variuos arrays but that does not feel right.

Any help deeply appreciated.

Comment: .Net 4 allows for generics in XAML using a format like `<Collections:List x:TypeArguments="System:String" x:Key="ExpenseTypes" >` so maybe we will get it in a later version of WP7 OS.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your input. I solved this by making a static List in a helper file I'm using

    public static List<string> expensetypes = new List<string>(new string[] { 
                        AppResources.exHotel, 
                        AppResources.exTaxi, 
                        AppResources.exFuel,.....

I can then use this as

    return Tools.expensetypes[this._type];

Not ideal but working.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can always just add a string resource with the values separated by some char, like "Hotel,Taxi,..." and then just use [string.Split(',')](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but it seems kludgy. I can't believe there is no solution for this in the framework. Seems like something that would be needed a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
Thanks for your input. I solved this by making a static List in a helper file I'm using

```
public static List<string> expensetypes = new List<string>(new string[] { AppResources.exHotel,
```

AppResources.exTaxi, 
AppResources.exFuel,.....

I can then use this as

```
return Tools.expensetypes[this._type];
```

Not ideal but working.